MAUI: How to log crash details in release mode
I am working with .NET MAUI to build mobile application for Android and IOS.
There is no issue while debugging the application on emulator.
But App crashes after few seconds of splash screen is shown with release build in physical devices (Android).
I have not aware how to log such issues, or what has been causing the issue.
Edit: I want help on how to log details about the crash and issues causing it. Not on the issues itself.

maybe you can post what you have done, your question needs more clarity, maybe post some code on github

@NitinS I want help on logging the details of the crash. Will it need code to be shared

You need to first determine what kind of crash this is.

@shingo I am not sure what it means. Can you help me with any resources that i can determine its type.

You can check the logcat to see if there is any log about crash or exception.

I suggest to use a 3pp logging service such as Sentry (others are available)
https://sentry.io/for/dotnet-maui/
It really is very simple.  Create a free account and register your app.  You will be provided a DSN code, you need to store this and add it into your app below.
Then in your CreateMauiApp() method add this
 var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
 builder
 .UseMauiApp<App>()

        // Add this section anywhere on the builder:
     .UseSentry(options =>
     {
            // The DSN is the only required setting.
            options.Dsn = "Your DSN url value is entered here";

            // Use debug mode if you want to see what the SDK is doing.
            // Debug messages are written to stdout with Console.Writeline,
            // and are viewable in your IDE's debug console or with 'adb logcat', etc.
            // This option is not recommended when deploying your application.
            options.Debug = true;

            // Set TracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of transactions for tracing.
            // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
            options.TracesSampleRate = 1.0;

            // Other Sentry options can be set here.
        })

Then when you catch exceptions, just log it to Sentry
catch (Exception ex)
{
    SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
    //Your normal logging & handling
}

It will also capture unhanded exceptions and has a lot of features to enable you to customise and enrich the errors.

For this, you can use Diagnostics to achieve this.
App Center Diagnostics is a cloud service that helps developers monitor the health of an application, delivering the data needed to understand what happens when an app fails during testing or in the wild. The App Center Diagnostics SDK collects information about crashes and errors in your apps and uploads them to the App Center portal for analysis by the development team- eliminating the guesswork about what really happened in the app when it failed.
For Maui, you can check document Get Started with MAUI and Xamarin.
And from the official note, we could know:

Visual Studio App Center is scheduled for retirement on March 31,
2025. While you can continue to use Visual Studio App Center until it is fully retired, there are several recommended alternatives that you
may consider migrating to: Learn more about support timelines and
alternatives.

